# In Python, how can I request specific data from a dynamically loaded website?

Tags: php, python, html, request

I want to load pages from [PeoplePerHour.com](http://www.peopleperhour.com) into python to run some data analysis, but it keeps getting data from a page I didn't ask for, I think it must go to the main page and then refreshes somehow into the page I ask for.

For example: 
I want to pull the prices from all users at http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst, and the data spans over multiple pages.

Say I want to request page 2, http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst#page=2. If I go here in a browser, it works fine and pulls up page 2, but I think it pulls up page one first and then "refreshes" into page 2 (I think). If I access this in python, it loads the HTML from the first page, and never sees page 2.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from pattern import web
import re
import pandas as pd

def list_of_prices(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    dom = web.DOM(html)
    list = []
    for person in dom('.freelancer-list-item .medium.price-tag'):
        currency = person('sup')
        amount = person('span')
        list.append([currency[0].content if currency else 'na', amount[0].content if amount else 'na'])
    return list

list_of_prices('http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst#page=2')
```

No matter what, this returns the prices from page 1.

What is going on that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through the pages.  If that's the case, I believe the problem is with your URL.

Here's the URL you gave:
http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst#page=2

The problem is, "page" is not a bookmark on that page.  When you use the #page=2, it tells the browser to go down to the same page for a bookmark called "page=2".

Here's the URL for the Next button in that site:
http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?sort=most-relevant&page=2

You'll see it says "&page=2" which means something else.  In their code "page" is a variable being passed via the url, with a value of 2.  You use the "&" if there are more than one of these variables.  Also, you are missing a "?" symbol.  If you're passing variables via the URL, you have to put a ? followed by the name=value pairs for your variables.

So, easy fix, change your url to this:

```
http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=2
```

That's in comparison to your old url:

```
http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst#page=2
```

As a quick test, copy/paste the corrected url on your web browser.  You will see it now is on page 2.

Answer (score 1):

Getting dynamic content (those generated by client-side code) is always very tricky. There is no easy solution to this, but if you really want to dig into it, I recommend [`PyV8`](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/), a `JavaScript` engine in `Python`.

Answer (score 1):

[Error in pattern when using pattern3 in python 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY4J8.png)

Please click on the above Hyperlink to open  the Image 
What is the alternative to executing the same code under python3.6 environment because due to this I have to install the pattern3, the pattern is not supported by the python 3.6
Thanks!